# Error with command line script task in Azure DevOps

Tags: bash, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I have a command-line task in Azure DevOps pipelines, it's currently failing due to syntax errors. The build pipeline has a variable defined. I have used the Azure PowerShell task, command line, and bash task.

Below is the complete yaml pipeline

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: self
    type: git
    ref: refs/heads/main

variables:

 - name: trivyVersion
   value: 0.9.1

 - name: location_id
   value: 44

jobs:
- job: Job_1
  displayName: Build and push image
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-20.04
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    clean: true
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: dummy env vars
    inputs:
      script: >
        echo "here"

  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: Download & Install Trivy
    inputs:
      script: >2-
            sudo apt-get install rpm
            wget https://github.com/aquasecurity/trivy/releases/download/v$(trivyVersion)/trivy_$(trivyVersion)_Linux-64bit.deb
            sudo dpkg -i trivy_$(trivyVersion)_Linux-64bit.deb
            trivy -v
  - task: AzurePowerShell@5
    displayName: Run Trivy Scan
    enabled: False
    inputs:
      ConnectedServiceNameARM: 53c02cd9-7170-42f0-88f9-3b2409fa3ed1
      ScriptType: InlineScript
      Inline: "make build\ndocker ps\ndocker images\nls $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\n#trivy image s_r2n0:latest\n\necho $acceptVulnerabilitiesFound\nwrite-output $acceptVulnerabilitiesFound\n\nif ($acceptVulnerabilitiesFound -eq 'Yes' )\n{\n#      trivy image s_r2n0:latest \n      trivy image --exit-code 0 --severity CRITICAL s_r2n0:latest\n}\nelse\n{\n      trivy image --exit-code 1 --severity CRITICAL s_r2n0:latest\n}"
      CustomTargetAzurePs: (Get-Module azure).Version
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: Command Line Script
    enabled: False
    inputs:
      script: >
        echo $acceptVulnerabilitiesFound
               if [ "${{ acceptVulnerabilitiesFound }}" == "Yes" ]; then
               echo 1
               else
                   echo 2
               fi
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: Bash Script
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: >
        ls $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
        echo $acceptVulnerabilitiesFound
        echo ${{variables.acceptVulnerabilitiesFound  }}
               if [ "${{ variables.acceptVulnerabilitiesFound }}" == "Yes" ]; then
               echo '1'
               else
                   echo '2'
               fi
...
```

#################

In the above, I have a powershell option, command line and bash. I couldn't get any to work. My preference is the powershell option, bash and command line are optionals.

I got the error,  `${{variables.acceptVulnerabilitiesFound  }}: bad substitution`

How would one also print out variables in the Azure option, with bash I know one can use echo?

Is it possible to have a build pipeline that accepts a parameter not a variable?

Comment: can you share your Yaml file or all that task as complete script

Comment: @Maytham Fahmi question edited, thanks.

Comment: I will look at it tomorrow

Comment: @learner as per the error you received can you change the curly braces used in your script to parentheses. As because Curly braces re for variable substitution.

Comment: I tried to use your definition but the pipeline works well.